# Creating and Use a PyTorch DataLoader

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to create a PyTorch Dataset and DataLoader object using a sample data.

This is the tab seperated dataset:

```
1 0  0.171429  1 0 0  0.966805  0
0 1  0.085714  0 1 0  0.188797  1
1 0  0.000000  0 0 1  0.690871  2
1 0  0.057143  0 1 0  1.000000  1
0 1  1.000000  0 0 1  0.016598  2
1 0  0.171429  1 0 0  0.802905  0
0 1  0.171429  1 0 0  0.966805  1
1 0  0.257143  0 1 0  0.329876  0
```

This is the code to create the Dataset above and DataLoader object:

```
import numpy as np
import torch as T
device = T.device("cpu")  # to Tensor or Module

# ---------------------------------------------------

# predictors and label in same file
# data has been normalized and encoded like:
#   sex     age      region   income    politic
#   [0]     [2]       [3]      [6]       [7]
#   1 0   0.057143   0 1 0    0.690871    2

class PeopleDataset(T.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, src_file, num_rows=None):
    x_tmp = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=num_rows,
      usecols=range(0,7), delimiter="\t",
      skiprows=0, dtype=np.float32)
    y_tmp = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=num_rows,
      usecols=7, delimiter="\t", skiprows=0,
      dtype=np.long)

    self.x_data = T.tensor(x_tmp,
      dtype=T.float32).to(device)
    self.y_data = T.tensor(y_tmp,
      dtype=T.long).to(device)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.x_data)  # required

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if T.is_tensor(idx):
      idx = idx.tolist()
    preds = self.x_data[idx, 0:7]
    pol = self.y_data[idx]
    sample = \
      { 'predictors' : preds, 'political' : pol }
    return sample

# ---------------------------------------------------

def main():
  print("\nBegin PyTorch DataLoader demo ")

  # 0. miscellaneous prep
  T.manual_seed(0)
  np.random.seed(0)

  print("\nSource data looks like: ")
  print("1 0  0.171429  1 0 0  0.966805  0")
  print("0 1  0.085714  0 1 0  0.188797  1")
  print(" . . . ")

  # 1. create Dataset and DataLoader object
  print("\nCreating Dataset and DataLoader ")

  train_file = "people_train.txt"
  train_ds = PeopleDataset(train_file, num_rows=8)

  bat_size = 3
  train_ldr = T.utils.data.DataLoader(train_ds,
    batch_size=bat_size, shuffle=True)

  # 2. iterate thru training data twice
  for epoch in range(2):
    print("\n==============================\n")
    print("Epoch = " + str(epoch))
    for (batch_idx, batch) in enumerate(train_ldr):
      print("\nBatch = " + str(batch_idx))
      X = batch['predictors']  # [3,7]
      # Y = T.flatten(batch['political'])  # 
      Y = batch['political']   # [3]
      print(X)
      print(Y)
  print("\n==============================")

  print("\nEnd demo ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The code is simply saved with the filename "**demo.py**". The code should succesfully execute once the command '**python demo.py**' is executed on a command prompt screen. I use Anaconda Prompt which has Torch (v 1.10) installed.

I have tried numerous methods to get the above working, but I only get an error which says:

```
Source data looks like: 
1 0  0.171429  1 0 0  0.966805  0
0 1  0.085714  0 1 0  0.188797  1
 . . . 

Creating Dataset and DataLoader 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-8-cfb1177991f2> in <module>()
     81 
     82 if __name__ == "__main__":
---> 83   main()

4 frames

<ipython-input-8-cfb1177991f2> in main()
     59 
     60   train_file = "people_train.txt"
---> 61   train_ds = PeopleDataset(train_file, num_rows=8)
     62 
     63   bat_size = 3

<ipython-input-8-cfb1177991f2> in __init__(self, src_file, num_rows)
     20     x_tmp = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=num_rows,
     21       usecols=range(0,7), delimiter="\t",
---> 22       skiprows=0, dtype=np.float32)
     23     y_tmp = np.loadtxt(src_file, max_rows=num_rows,
     24       usecols=7, delimiter="\t", skiprows=0,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin, encoding, max_rows)
   1137         # converting the data
   1138         X = None
-> 1139         for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
   1140             if X is None:
   1141                 X = np.array(x, dtype)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in read_data(chunk_size)
   1058                 continue
   1059             if usecols:
-> 1060                 vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
   1061             if len(vals) != N:
   1062                 line_num = i + skiprows + 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1058                 continue
   1059             if usecols:
-> 1060                 vals = [vals[j] for j in usecols]
   1061             if len(vals) != N:
   1062                 line_num = i + skiprows + 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am not able to see which part of the index is wrong, as I don't feel there seem to be anything wrong with the indexing. Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to be space-separated, not tab-separated. So, when you specify `delimiter="\t"`, the entire row is read as a single column. But because of `usecols=range(0,7)`, NumPy expects there to be seven columns, and throws an error when trying to iterate over them.

To fix this, either change the whitespaces to tabs in your data, or change the delimiter argument to `delimiter=" "`.